# Remote XML parsing by calling URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse xml data by calling url via **file_get_contents()** in php. The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RESPONSE>
<SINGLE>
<KEY name="sitename"><VALUE>RedCross Test</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="username"><VALUE>test1</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="firstname"><VALUE>Test1</VALUE>
</KEY>
<KEY name="lastname"><VALUE>testTest1</VALUE>
</KEY>
</SINGLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

Here is the procedure:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$xml_obj = file_get_contents("http://localhost/example/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=".$token."&function=get_info");

$data = $xml_obj->SINGLE->KEY[2]->VALUE;
echo $data;

?>
```

The response is: error on line 2 at column 1: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 7. Could someone advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is stating that `$xml_obj` is not an object. That's because it's not. It's simply a var storing the contents (as a string) of the response from `file_get_contents`.

Instead of:

```
$xml_obj = file_get_contents("http://localhost/example/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=".$token."&function=get_info");
```

Try:

```
$xml_obj = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/example/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=".$token."&function=get_info");
```

Or, if you need to use the contents for other stuff and want it in a separate variable:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://localhost/example/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=".$token."&function=get_info");

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML( $contents );
```

Answer (score 3):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) just returns the XML code as a string without parsing it. You probably want to use [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents returns a **STRING**. e.g. raw xml. you need to load that string into DOM or Simple_XML before you can do the `->xxx` stuff on it:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('...');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
etc...
```